# What is the conjugate of a polynomial > binomial?

Tags: number-theory

I have recently learned that the conjugate of a binomial such as (x+y) is (x-y) or (x+1) is (x-1).

But what if I have a polynomial with more than 2 terms like $(x^2+x+1)$ or (x+y+z) or (x+y+1) ?

Do these higher than second order nomials have conjugates or is it specific to binomials?

My thoughts are something like:

The conjugate of (x+y+z) is (x-y-z), but then again why would only x not change sign? So this can't be right.

Maybe polynomials do not have conjugate pairs, maybe they have conjugate sets.

So the conjugate set of (x+y+z) might be something like [(x+y-z),(x-y+z),(x-y-z)].

If this is true then an n-polynomial has ($2^{(n-1)}-1$) members in its conjugate set.

I don't know, these are just my thoughts.

Does (x+y+z) have a conjugate and if so what is it?

Comment: The reason you have conjugate is to get square terms: $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$. What would be the purpose of a conjugate of a polynomial with more than 3 terms?

Comment: @Adrei you can treat any polynomial with more than two terms as one with two by parentheses... Just cause something sounds stupid don't mean it is.